# How to find rows with similar data as a specific row in sql

Tags: sql

Let me make it clear -

I have a table with information such as CourseID, Semester, GPA

I need to find all the CourseID's that have the same GPA(and some more fields) as CourseID='999'

I would also like a solution with AND without nested SELECT

Thanks!

[image]

So I have to find all the courseCode that has the same GPA and FailPerc as (Code 999, Year 2011, Sem B, Date 2)

Hope it's more clean now

Comment: Either you need to clarify your question or look back at the basics of SQL.

Answer (score 2):

this might work...

```
select c1.* 
from course c1
inner join course c2 on c1.pga= c2.pga
where c2.courseid = 999
and c1.courseid <> c2.courseid
```

with subselects

```
select c1.*
from couser c1
where pga = (select pga 
             from course c2 
             where c2.courseid=999)
and c1.courseid <> 999
```

Comment: You might add "and c1.courseid <> c2.courseid" to avoid same-row match.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run any query you need to somehow retrieve the data for the original data row. Unless you're writing your SQL for something like MS Access and can use domain functions like [DLOOKUP](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php)(), I don't see any other way how you can get this information. This means, you need at least 2 SELECT queries and they must be nested.